# AllwaySync does not AutoStart in Win8

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync, autostart

I want to get my AllwaySync program to launch automatically after log on to Windows 8. I tried to check the AutoStart box in the preferences of the program as well as I tried to move a shortcut of the program to the AutoStart Folder. TaskManager and CCleaner both say, that AllwaySync should start automatically, but it does not. It even does not work if I set the exe file to be always executed as Admin and/or in Compatibility mode...

Comment: Contact the `AllwaySync` author as it sounds like a problem with the program itself.